# HTML not working fine with string builder in C# ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, string, stringbuilder

```
sb.Append("<table style='border:1px solid black; border-collapse:collapse; width:100%;'>");
        sb.Append("<tr style='background:rgb(146,208,80); border:1px solid black;'>");
        sb.Append("<th style='border: 1px solid black; text-align:center; padding:0%;'>"); sb.Append("OPUS ID"); sb.Append("</th>");
        sb.Append("<th style='border: 1px solid black; text-align:center; padding:0%;'>"); sb.Append("Location"); sb.Append("</th>");
        sb.Append("<th style='border: 1px solid black; text-align:center; padding:0%;'>"); sb.Append("WMS #"); sb.Append("</th>");
        sb.Append("<th style='border: 1px solid black; text-align:center; padding:0%;'>"); sb.Append("Carton ID"); sb.Append("</th>");
        sb.Append("<th style='border: 1px solid black; text-align:center; padding:0%;'>"); sb.Append("Tracking #"); sb.Append("</th>");
        sb.Append("<th style='border: 1px solid black; text-align:center; padding:0%;'>"); sb.Append("Delivery Date"); sb.Append("</th>");
        sb.Append("<th style='border: 1px solid black; text-align:center; padding:0%;'>"); sb.Append("Carton Status"); sb.Append("</th>");
        sb.Append("<th style='border: 1px solid black; text-align:center; padding:0%;'>"); sb.Append("SKU"); sb.Append("</th>");
        sb.Append("<th style='border: 1px solid black; text-align:center; padding:0%;'>"); sb.Append("SKU Description"); sb.Append("</th>");
        sb.Append("<th style='border: 1px solid black; text-align:center; padding:0%;'>"); sb.Append("Qty Outstanding"); sb.Append("</th>");
        sb.Append("</tr>");

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            sb.Append("<tr style='border:1px solid green; border-collapse: collapse; width:100%;'>");

            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                sb.Append("<td style='border:1px solid black; border-collapse:collapse; text-align:center; padding:0%;'>");
                string file = row.Field<string>(i);
                sb.Append(file + "</td>");
            }

            sb.Append("</tr>");
        }

        sb.Append("</table>");
```

Above code is making HTML Table and binding it in email body, but something wrong happening.

image are for clear view:

[image]

Comment: What exactly is the HTML that is generated around the problem spots? I guess some data is interpreted as markup. Is there any reason why you are not using Razor to generate this table?

Comment: [HtmlEncode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.htmlencode) the field-values before you add them to the StringBuilder (which Razor would do automatically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @Hans Kesting using Razor syntax would be best. Especially helpful would be to move away from DataSets and DataTabes and use models for your data. This would make iterating through your data and populating a table much easier with something like [WebGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.helpers.webgrid?view=aspnet-webpages-3.2). However, if none of this is possible what I have done in the past is:

- create the HTML table string in a Helper method
- pass the HTML string to a Controller action method
- store the HTML string into the TempData object
- access the TempData object and render the table to the view using:

  @Html.Raw(TempData["html"])